# Room Invalidation tracker is initialized twice

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I have a horizontal recycler view with custom items in it . Each item can hold the position of current item in the Recycler view . I want to update the item position when item is moved using drag and drop . However the data is getting deleted when there are more then three items in horizontal view.Please Help me out .
[Source Code](https://github.com/parmarravi/HorizontalRecyclerView)

This is what i am getting in Logcat:

> E/ROOM: Invalidation tracker is initialized twice :/.
>
> E/Item moved: Counterfrom3
>
> next item:to2

Initialization of database in onCreate.

```
 db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
```

RecyclerView Adapter code.

```
@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    String name = dataSet.get(fromPosition).getName();
    //this will make "Add item" do not move from its first position..
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (!(Objects.equals(name, "Add") || (toPosition == 0 && fromPosition == 1))) {
            Collections.swap(dataSet, fromPosition, toPosition);
            MoveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code to update the data when items are moved.

```
 public static void MoveItem(int fromPosition,int toPosition){
        String name = data.get(fromPosition).getName(); //This gets the current item name in the view 
        String nexName = data.get(toPosition).getName(); //This gets the next item name in the view 

        ContentValues fromContentValues = new ContentValues();
        fromContentValues.put("posItem", toPosition); //adding data to ContentValues
        ContentValues toContentValues = new ContentValues();
        toContentValues.put("posItem", fromPosition);
        Log.e("Item moved", name + "from" + fromPosition + "\n" + "next item:" + "to" + toPosition);

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
        db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().update(name,
                0, fromContentValues, "posItem =" + fromPosition, null);

        db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().update(nexName,
                0, toContentValues, "posItem =" + toPosition, null);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful(); //setting Transaction Successful
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction(); // commit or rollback
            db.close(); //closing database
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looking forward for the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I migrate the database version, same error happens `E/ROOM: Invalidation tracker is initialized twice`, kills the app, and reopens work. When I started using Room v1.1.0.

But if I keep everything the same and go back to using Room v1.0.0, no such problem occurs and everything works perfectly.

So, May be Room v1.1.0 issue

[google issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65820362)

Comment: also you can try This, It work for me: ```compile ("android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1-rc1")``

Comment: It maybe caused by this bug : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79362399
Fixed in version 1.1.1

Comment: its still coming on 2.2.5

Comment: The problem is still there on 2.3.0, are we sure it's really a bug?