# Android Room DB: Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed?

Tags: android, database-migration, android-room

I'm using ROOM DB for Android.
I have a same issue with [Upgrading Room DB with migrations causes DB lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420649/upgrading-room-db-with-migrations-causes-db-lock)

My ROOM version is 1.1.1-rc and the problem occurs again.
I think there are temporary solutions such as changing DB name, etc. However, it is not the exact solution for migration.

Is there any solution for this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Even though I added a migration rule (e.g., .addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)), same issue occurs again.
I couldn't exact solution yet.

Since I cannot find the exact solution, I use an indirect way as follows.
In my case, referred from https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/access-room-database-version-at-runtime/, after checking db version and hard-coded version, I delete previous version DB before open Room DB if version is not matched.

Comment: In my case, if I remove SQLiteSecureOpenHelper for secure Room DB, migration performs well! However, if SQLiteSecureOpenHelper is applied, "Invalidation tracker is initialized twice" error always occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper (which is the default openHelper of Room), custom open helper should not open at onOpen only for migration

```
@Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        if (!mMigrated) {
            // if we've migrated, we'll re-open the db so we  should not call the callback.
            this.mCallback.onOpen(this.getWrappedDb(db));
        }
    }
```